# How to get reference to google map object inside a VueJs component?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

This is my VueJs component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <gmap-map ref="map" :center="center" @click="captureClickedLocation" :zoom="10">
    </gmap-map>
  </div>
</template>
```

How to get the reference to the current map object here, in order to use it with a `google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager` to display custom overlays, for example ?

Example code would be sth like this

```
var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
                        drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
                        drawingControl: true,
                        drawingControlOptions: {
                            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
                            drawingModes: [
                                google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE,
                                google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
                                google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE
                            ]
                        },
                        markerOptions: {
                            icon: 'images/beachflag.png'
                        });
drawingManager.setMap(map);
```

How to get the reference to the **gmap-map**'s map object? or, what would be the value for **map** in the last line ?

PS: I'm using ***vue-google-maps*** from **https://github.com/xkjyeah/vue-google-maps**, which is vue wrapper for google maps.

Comment: For reference you can use this.$refs['map'].

Comment: yes, but that just returns HTML DOM element, not the google map object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`this.$refs.map.$mapObject` or `this.$refs['map'].$mapObject`

Answer (score -1):

For reference you can use this.$refs['map'].